# Rails 3 Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost. Application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-pow

**Problem:**

My local website is running super slow (2 minutes to load the site) . Not sure if it's related to my recent Yosemite upgrade. Before the upgrade everything is running fine and the code is also running fine on the online web server but not locally. I'm using pow to host the site locally.

**Error in Safari:**

*Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost. Application.js*

**Error in Chrome:**

*Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH Applicaton.js*

**Gems:**

http://pastie.org/private/4eql90m3nw4s5ddpckprbg

**Gemfile.lock:**

http://pastie.org/private/wxhxjjctlyenorwxexa9oq

**System:**

- ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
- Rails 3.2.17
- rvm 1.25.34
- OSX 10.10
- pow 0.5.0

**EDIT1:**

I did a fresh install and had to install libv8 via home-brew.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following things:

1. Imploded rvm. `rvm implode`
2. Reinstalled rvm `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
3. Upgraded to ruby 2.1.4 `rvm install ruby 2.1.4`
4. Replaced `gem pry-debugger` with `gem byebug`
5. Replaced `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby` with `gem 'execjs', '~> 2.2.2'`

After that all the gems installed correctly and the site is up and running.